# Converting .dot file to .pdf in Decision Trees in SciKit Learn

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree

I run the code included in the SciKit Learn documentation (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html).

The code is the following:

```
    from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
    from sklearn import tree
    iris = load_iris()
    clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
    clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

    with open("iris.dot", 'w') as f:
         f = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=f)
```

When I enter the final command though I get an error message:

```
    dot -Tpdf iris.dot -o iris.pdf
    File "<ipython-input-23-f3425d4a118a>", line 1
    dot -Tpdf iris.dot -o iris.pdf
             ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I wonder what I am doing wrong.  Could you help me?  Thank you.

Comment: this is to be done from the console, not in your python code / interpreter

Comment: Can you become more specific?  I open the Anaconda prompt and then I move to which directory and enter the above command?

Comment: `I open the Anaconda prompt [...]` - no. You have to use the shell of your operating system. This is not python code. So the python/anaconda prompt will not work.

Comment: I used Windows commander --I have Windows 10-- and entered the command.  An error message ensued:  'dot' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: it's provided by the graphviz package if I am not mistaken: https://github.com/conda-forge/graphviz-feedstock

Comment: I installed the graphviz package using conda install graphviz but I still get the same error message when I enter: "dot -Tpdf iris.dot -o iris.pdf" in the Windows commander.